# OpenMetadata with own Airflow running in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to run OpenMetadata in k8s using the [official helm chart](https://github.com/open-metadata/openmetadata-helm-charts), but I want to use my already running Airflow instance.

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.open-metadata.org/deployment/airflow) to set up the openmetadata dependencies in the airflow containers.

And my values.yml for the openmetadata chart looks like this:

```
global:
  logLevel: DEBUG
  airflow:
    enabled: true
     # endpoint url for airflow
    host: airflow-webserver.etl.svc.cluster.local:8080
    auth:
      username: admin
      password: 
        secretRef: airflow-pw
        secretKey: openmetadata-airflow-password
```

Airflow web server is running in namespace etl and openmetadata in default.
My problem is that openmetadata is not finding the managed airflow APIs and I don't understand why.

Using the browser, I can access the APIs at http://{AIRFLOW_HOST}:{AIRFLOW_PORT}/rest_api/.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To use managed Airflow APIs, you need to install a package in your Airflow. Alternatively, you can install the openmeta-data airflow, which comes with all the relevant dependencies pre-installed.

You can still use your Airflow template environment and so on, but by installing their image, you'll get everything you need. For instance, if you install openmetadata ([helm chart 0.0.53](https://github.com/open-metadata/openmetadata-helm-charts/blob/openmetadata-dependencies-0.0.53/charts/openmetadata/Chart.yaml#L18)), you can also get the relevant [Airflow image](https://github.com/open-metadata/openmetadata-helm-charts/blob/openmetadata-dependencies-0.0.53/charts/deps/values.yaml#LL56C1-L57C1).